# Reading XML using XMLReader and Stream objects

Tags: xml, vb.net, filestream, xmlreader, cryptostream

To put it simply, I am having an issue when passing **Stream** objects to the **XMLReader** object's **Create(*Stream*)** function.

The following is a segment of code from the application I am creating to read encrypted and un-encrypted XML files stored locally.

```
        Using fileStream As New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

            Dim reader As XmlReader = Nothing

            Try
                Dim encoder = GetEncoder()
                Using cs As New CryptoStream(fileStream, encoder.CreateDecryptor(encoder.Key, encoder.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                    reader = XmlReader.Create(cs)
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                reader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream)
            End Try

            If reader IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    Me.ReadXML(reader)
                Finally
                    reader.Close()
                    reader = Nothing
                End Try
            End If

        End Using
```

When using streams, I get the following exceptions on the first few iterations of the stream's **read** method inside the **ReadXML** function.

> 1. System.Xml.XmlException: There are multiple root elements. Line 2, position 26.
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
> 2. System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()

If I just decrypt the XML into plain-text and write it as file, I can use the **XMLTextReader** and pass the path of the decrypted file into the constructor to read the XML file just fine.

I know my XML file is formatted correctly as the **XMLTextReader** can parse through it with no issues when ONLY passing the file path.  For reference, here is a snapshot of my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="">
    <Book name="Foo" author="Bar" />
    <Book name="Bat" author="Widget" />
</Books>
```

I also know the **ReadXML** method works correctly for the same reason as above.

For reference my **ReadXML** method looks like this...

```
Sub ReadXML(reader As XmlReader)

    Do While reader.Read()

        Select Case reader.NodeType
            Case XmlNodeType.Element

                Select Case reader.Name.ToLower()
                    Case "x"
                        x=1
                    Case "y"
                        y=2
                    Case "z"
                        z=3
                End Select

            Case XmlNodeType.Text
                x=a
                y=b
                z=c
            Case XmlNodeType.EndElement

                Select Case reader.Name.ToLower()
                    Case "a"
                       a=1
                    Case "b"
                       b=2
                    Case "c"
                       c=3
                End Select

        End Select

    Loop

End Sub
```

Can anyone explain why creating an **XMLReader** with **Stream** objects would give me these exceptions?
Does it have something to do with where the **Stream** starts reading?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's because it believes there are more than one root node. I.e., you don't have 1 parent root node with multiple books within it. You have books lined back to back. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042902/xml-error-there-are-multiple-root-elements

Comment: I don't think so. The XML file as is can be read with the XMLTextReader when passing the path to the file BUT not when passing a FileStream previously created. Using the same file with different objects passed to the constructor gives different results. The XML file provided clearly shows only a single root node.